# Exclude ending zeroes, and duplicate elements from a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm having trouble with my Java assignment where I have to sort an array and print the array in ascending order excluding empty indices and duplicate items.

I have most of the project figured out but I'm not sure how to exclude the ending zeroes that I'm getting at the end of the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* Project4.java  InsertInOrder with bSearch optimization to compute insertion index */
// YOUR NAME/ID: 

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project4
{
    static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;

    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length < 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Must put input filename on cmd line\n");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner infile = new Scanner( new File( args[0] ) );        

        int[] arr = new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        int count= 0;

        while ( infile.hasNextInt() )
        {
            if ( count==arr.length ) arr = upSizeArr(arr);
            if (insertInOrder( arr, count, infile.nextInt() ) )
            ++count;
        }

        arr=trimArr(arr,count); // Now count == .length
        printArray( arr );  // we trimmed it thus count == length so we don't bother to pass in count

    }

    // ############################################################################################################

    static void printArray( int[] arr  )
    {
        for( int i=0 ; i<arr.length ;++i )
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " " );
        System.out.println();
    }

    static int[] upSizeArr( int[] fullArr )
    {
        int[] upSizedArr = new int[ fullArr.length * 2 ];
        for ( int i=0; i<fullArr.length ; ++i )
            upSizedArr[i] = fullArr[i];
        return upSizedArr;
    }

    static int[] trimArr( int[] oldArr, int count )
    {

        int[] trimmedArr = new int[ count ];
        int j=0;

        for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++)
        {
            int currentElement =oldArr[i];
            if(currentElement!=oldArr[i+1])
                trimmedArr[j++]=currentElement;

        }
        trimmedArr[j++]=oldArr[count-1];
        return trimmedArr;

    }

    static boolean insertInOrder( int[] arr, int count, int newVal )
    {
         int idx = bSearch( arr, count, newVal ); 
        if ( idx < 0 )
            idx=-(idx+1);
        int pos = count;
        while(pos>0 && newVal<(arr[pos-1]))
        {
            arr[pos]=arr[pos-1];
            pos--;
        }
        arr[idx] = newVal;
        return true;
    }

    static int bSearch(int[] a, int count, int key)
    {
        int lo =0;
        int hi=count-1;
        int mid = 0;
        while(lo<=hi)
        {
            mid=lo +(hi-lo)/2;
            if(a[mid]>key)
                hi=mid-1;
            else if(a[mid]<key)
                lo=mid+1;
            else
                return -(mid+1);
        }
        return -(lo+1); 
    }
}
```

Input file `P4input.txt`:

```
100 89 65 46 32 90 50 38 67 71 42 92 99 57 90 89 98 34 85 19 60 15 99 79 57
```

Comment: what is `empty indices` in array?

Comment: by empty I just meant indices that have the value zero

Comment: ok, what should be printed for array like `{-1, 0, 1}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new array whose length is equal to the remaining elements, copy the elements into it, and return this new array.

Change the definition of `trimArr` as follows to fix the issue:

```
static int[] trimArr(int[] oldArr, int count) {    
    int[] tempArr = new int[count];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        int currentElement = oldArr[i];
        if (currentElement != oldArr[i + 1])
            tempArr[j++] = currentElement;

    }
    tempArr[j++] = oldArr[count - 1];

    int[] trimmedArr = new int[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        trimmedArr[i] = tempArr[i];
    }
    return trimmedArr;
}
```

**Note:** Such problems are better to be solved using a dynamic list e.g. `ArrayList`. However, probably your teacher won't allows using `ArrayList` at this stage.

Comment: I've been staring at this code for so long I didn't even think to create another temp array. Thank you so much ! Yeah the problem was supposed to be solved without using Arraylists. Thanks again!